Multiple Kerberos errors on our domain
Can anybody assist me? We are having thousands of Kerberos errors on our domain and I just can't gather enough info to troubleshoot. It seems to be happening everywhere on the domain. I have some software I wrote which syncs from a database to AD and each time I authenticate it generates these events yet it still succeeds. I really don't know what else to check.
0x6 KDC_ERR_C_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN
0x19 KDC_ERR_PREAUTH_REQUIRED


An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x80000003

Time Generated: 12/20/2024   08:30:41

Event String:
        A Kerberos error message was received:

         on logon session <omitted domain name>\dc-ch-2$

         Client Time:
         Server Time: 15:30:41.0000 12/20/2024 Z

         Error Code: 0x6 KDC_ERR_C_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN

         Extended Error:

         Client Realm:
         Client Name:
         Server Realm: <omitted domain name>
         Server Name: krbtgt/<omitted domain name>
         Target Name: krbtgt/<omitted domain name>

         Error Text:

         File: onecore\ds\security\protocols\kerberos\client2\logonapi.cxx

         Line: e11

         Error Data is in record data.


Logon type 3 means network logon.
0xC0000064 - "User logon with misspelled or bad user account".
0x6 KDC_ERR_C_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN implies Service Principal Name (SPN) access problem.
It seems that you logon to domain over network from DC-CH-2 and IP address in the event log, but Kerberos protocol does not accept username (in this case computer$ account).

Pls chk if you have recently took DC-CH-2 out of Active Directory domain or changed DNS Server IP address of this computer?

Pls chk the time sync between the computers involved in the script and domain controllers. This should be at most 5 mins (Kerberos req) Is it GMT-7 for the computer time-zone settings, I have seen 7 hrs difference in the logs.

On DC-CH-2 does klist command list TGT (Ticket Granting Ticket) after logging onto domain? The user should automatically get TGT after logging on.

Check DC-CH-2 computer secure channel with PDC Emulator role:
netdom verify /d:.


If there is a problem with secure channel should be reset or if this is a Domain Controller, this role may need to be reinstalled.

Pls check also setspn -L DC-CH-2. The list should be similar to other computers in the domain. SPNs are used for Kerberos to locate service names that are capable and that use Kerberos protocol.

